# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. React native error

Tags: react-native, button

when I add a button in my view, it throws me this error(in the title). the code works with that:

```
return (
        <View >
            <Text>trade</Text>
            <Button
                title="Press me"
                onPress={() => Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed')}
            />
        </View>
    ); 
}
```

but with this one it doesn't:

```
return (
        <View >
            <Text>trade</Text>
            
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: Can you show us more code of your functional class? Btw: Type <View> instead of <View >

Comment: I see the same code in both code blocks

Comment: @EVeras sorry i've changed it

Answer (score 0):

I ran this line of code on my terminal and it works now:
npm install -g react-native@latest